# Extract specific JS value from web page using BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract a field from the following web page: https://www.olx.bg/d/ad/podemnitsi-haspeli-tovarni-i-kuhnenski-asansori-motor-reduktori-CID1012-ID8pWNq.html

The value that I want to get is this one ( 3143 ):

[image]

I tried to do it, but no success, the value is JS generated. Here is my code so far.

```
page = requests.get('https://www.olx.bg/d/ad/podemnitsi-haspeli-tovarni-i-kuhnenski-asansori-motor-reduktori-CID1012-ID8pWNq.html')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

Do you have any idea how can I do this ?

Comment: Comes from a POST request to `https://www.olx.bg/api/v1/offers/124391060/page-views/` I think

Answer (score 0):

Check the source code of the webpage ( using `Ctrl + U` on the browser) and search your desired element whether they're present or not.

If they are present in the page source then extract them, it could be using regex if for example, they are inside a JSON.

If not try [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) library